# primitive of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

If it exists, find the primitive of $z^2+\frac{1}{z^2}$.
Here: 
I start my solution as follows. Since $z^2+\frac{1}{z^2}$ is holomorphic everywhere except at zero, hence its primitive is
$$F(z)=\int_{\gamma}z^2+\frac{1}{z^2}dz=z^3-\frac{1}{z}$$, where $\gamma$ is a piecewize smooth path in its domain starting at the origin.
Am I correct? Please I need comment.

Comment: are you sure that this function is holomorphic? $\frac{1}{z} = \frac{\bar{z}}{|z|^2}$ and $\partial \bar{z} f \neq 0$.

Comment: $\gamma$ can start at any point expect at origin. The primitive is $\frac{z^3}{3} - \frac{1}{z}$ upto an additive constant.

Comment: wow... I got my mistake. Thanks!